# Solving Integral with Known Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-transform

I was learning Fourier Transform recently, and I came across this question. Although I know how to complete the Fourier transform for a function, but how do you evaluate another integral with the known Fourier Transform?
Question as follows:
Find the Fourier Transform for this function:

$y(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
\pi ,& \left |x  \right | < 1\\
0,& \left | x \right | > 1
\end{array}
 \right.$

Hence Evaluate the integral:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{sinx}{x}\,dx\,.$

and also:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\,dx\,.$

From what I understand, Symmetry property of Fourier Transform may help!

Comment: Have you calculated the Fourier transform of $y$?

Comment: I believe it is as follows: '''f(k) =  \frac{i \pi }{k \sqrt{2 \pi } } (e^{-ik} - e^{ik} )'''

Comment: Can you simplify that expression? Remember how $\sin x$ can be written in terms of $e^{ix}$ and $e^{-ix}$.